# react hook forms and material ui: reset() not working after successfull form submit

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to submit a form using `react hook forms`. After submit  i want to clear all the fields. I have read about using `reset()`. But its not working

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import {
  Paper,
  Box,
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ResetPassword() {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    old_password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
    new_password1: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
    new_password2: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Paper variant="outlined">
        <Box px={3} py={2}>
          <Typography variant="h6" align="center" margin="dense">
            Change Password
          </Typography>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                label="Current Password"
                type="password"
                {...register("old_password")}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                label="New Password"
                type="password"
                {...register("new_password1")}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                label="Confirm New Password"
                type="password"
                {...register("new_password2")}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Box mt={3}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            >
              Change Password
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

How to reset the fields after submit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use RHF's `<Controller />` component here as `register` won't work with MUI's `<Textfield />` because it is an external controlled component. You can find [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) more information about integrating UI libraries.

One important thing is to pass `defaultValues` to `useForm`, as this is required when using `reset` for external controlled components ([Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset)).

> You will need to pass defaultValues to useForm in order to reset the
> Controller components' value.

```js
export default function ResetPassword() {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    old_password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
    new_password1: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
    new_password2: Yup.string().required("Password is required")
  });

  const { control, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      old_password: "",
      new_password1: "",
      new_password2: ""
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Paper variant="outlined">
        <Box px={3} py={2}>
          <Typography variant="h6" align="center" margin="dense">
            Change Password
          </Typography>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <Controller
                name="old_password"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    label="Current Password"
                    type="password"
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <Controller
                name="new_password1"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    label="New Password"
                    type="password"
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <Controller
                name="new_password2"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    label="Confirm New Password"
                    type="password"
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Box mt={3}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            >
              Change Password
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: apart from reset, the other things works well, without the controller

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's working well because `<TextField />`has a similiar props interface to an native `<input />`. But the `ref` prop, which `register` needs to link the actual input will reference the `<TextField />` root element and not the input. You can check it [here](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api). So basically the spread of the `register` call will set a `ref` prop, while `<TextField />` instead has an `inputRef` prop for referencing the input element.

Comment: I made an alternative [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-basic-forked-nnnhj?file=/src/index.js) where you can test this behaviour. I just destructered the `register` calls outside the template and linked the refs to the `inputRef` props of `<TextField />`. Then it will work with `register`, but using `<Controller />` here is in my opinion a much cleaner approach as it is also described to do it that way in the docs of RHF.

Comment: To complete the explanation - have a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/3b600f2c6a4860390711855f6ea735f70244b66a/src/logic/createFormControl.ts#L1087) of `reset`. There you can see, that `reset` needs the correct `ref` to access the actual input element.

Comment: `So basically the spread of the register call will set a ref prop` : Then how the register is still working previously if its refering to textfield and not input (where inputref refers to input instead of ref)

Comment: It's working because `<TextField />` has almost all the props that the `register` call returns. These are `name`, `onChange`, `onBlur` and `ref`. So RHF can set up the field and on change of the `<TextField />` input it will update the internal form state. [Here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/3b600f2c6a4860390711855f6ea735f70244b66a/src/types/form.ts#L151) you can find the return value of the `register` function. Only `ref` of the `<TextField />` is referencing the wrong element and therefore `reset` isn't working.

Comment: if `ref` of the <TextField /> is referencing the wrong element then how come the RHF is able to keep track of values. So what is the main purpose of ref.  How does RHF fetches the value of the input

Comment: Also we have to use `reset({old_password: "", new_password1: "", new_password2: "", })` or one has to mention default values